# Issue when deploying GRAV site using git on Gandi.net simple hosting

Tags: git, deployment, grav

I have a new site that I have prepared with [Grav](https://getgrav.org/) and that I'm willing to deploy on my [Simple hosting](https://www.gandi.net/en/simple-hosting) instance on gandi.net.

I have saved my developments using git on my bitbucket account. All fine.
I have configured my git access to the simple hosting. All fine as well.

But when I deployed my Grav code (the [deploy command on Gandi](https://doc.gandi.net/en/simple/git) is apparently a local git checkout), all my code was deployed at the host root, **besides** htdocs/ and not **into** it.

I then changed my local structure via git to include all my code into a local htdocs directory. But then, deploying it on Gandi returns me the following message:

```
initializing builder
......................builder ready
Vm password:
Grabbing terminal
Ok
-----> Starting new deployment (gare.humoeursvertes.net - master)
-----> Fetching application code
-----> Building new application
ERROR: composer.json and composer.lock files should be placed outside the htdocs directory (../htdocs/)
Dependencies could not be installed. Exiting...
Please refer to the documentation:

[fr] http://wiki.gandi.net/fr/simple/instance/php-mysql?&#composerlock
[en] http://wiki.gandi.net/en/simple/instance/php#dependency_management
-----> Building new application failed
-----> Aborting deployment
```

Apparently, I cannot do that :-( But what is the solution then? I cannot find any, and Gandi support is not responding...

I assume I should change the *target* directory of the deploy (aka git checkout) done on Gandi, but cannot find any way to do so. Any hint welcome !
Thanks,
Xavier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was much easier than expected. It is because the Grav packages come with `composer.json` and `composer.lock` configuration files, and Gandi does not accept such files in the htdocs directory.
I therefore had to
- keep everything into the `htdocs` directory
- but these two files that I have moved besides (and not inside) `htdocs`

Then the deploy works like a charm. (same solution as for a symfony deployment: http://rockstarninja.labak.xyz/gandi-sh-installation-de-symfony-3-2-sur-une-instance-simple-hosting-de-type-php-5-6/).